# Devise returns nil after User.first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm testing some associations after adding a new migration that associates users to many posts.

```
  class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
      create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Customization
      t.string :name
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      t.string   :confirmation_token
      t.datetime :confirmed_at
      t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps
     end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

After I migrated, I'm supposed to test with 

`u = User.first`

to receive this block of code make sure everything is running smoothly.

```
 User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 1, name: nil, email: "username@example.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$702fd8Io3WH7UTWoTY3rUeUJBcFVlsq8/K6ypPKZUQni...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2013-04-29 20:25:26", confirmation_sent_at: "2013-04-29 20:25:09", unconfirmed_email: nil, created_at: "2013-04-29 20:25:09", updated_at: "2013-04-29 20:25:26">
```

but I got `nil`

```
  2.1.5 :001 > u = User.first
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  => nil
```

Is this a bad thing? Why isn't anything showing up?

Comment: Before you test, you need to make sure that your database has data in it. looks like to me that your database is empty ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your database is empty at present. And hence you are getting a nil. You can do this:

1) Add a new user to the table using devise sign-up functionality in the front end.

2) Add seed data in the db/seeds.rb file like this:

```
User.find_or_create_by(:email => 'tester@test.com', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password')
```

Run `rake db:seed` from command prompt. Seeds data is the initial data that you want to add to your database for the application to run as desired.

3) Use Rails console: Run `rails c` in your command prompt and do this:

```
User.create(:email => 'tester@test.com', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this in your console to add the first user:

```
user = User.new(:email => 'tester@test.com', :password => 'testingpassword', 
:password_confirmation => 'testingpassword')
user.save
```

Devise doesn't create a default user for you, so until you create one, user.first wil come back as nil